# How to rename an existing file in VB Script?

Tags: vbscript

I am very new to VB Script. I am trying to rename a file through VB Script could any one please help me in this ?

I just tried this but didn't work.

```
Dim OldFile As String
Dim NewFile As String

OldFile = "C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.44\apache-tomcat-8.0.44\webapps\" & "\" & timeStampDir & "\" & "output_11.docx"

NewFile = "C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.44\apache-tomcat-8.0.44\webapps\" & "\" & timeStampDir & "\" & "output.docx"
        Name OldFile As NewFile
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**`FileSystemObject`**](https://ss64.com/vb/filesystemobject.html%20%22FileSystemObject') and use `Name` property of a object referring the file you want to rename.

```
Dim OldFile, FSO, objFile
Set FSO = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

OldFile = "C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.44\apache-tomcat-8.0.44\webapps\" + CStr(timeStampDir) + "\output_11.docx"

Set objFile = FSO.GetFile(OldFile)
objFile.Name = "output.docx"
```

Keep in mind that you need to correctly escape all of the whitespaces in your `oldFile` variable, otherwise the file may not be found.

Comment: Who is down-voting the answers? The answers are correct and working....

Comment: @MithileshIndurkar I also wanted to find out who. answers are working.

Answer (score -1):

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

objFSO.MoveFile OldFile, NewFile

Set objFSo = Nothing
```

Comment: I don't want to move, its in same folder.

Comment: This is just one of the easiest ways to rename the file. It does not create a duplicate file. Give it a try

Comment: Actually i am not from VB background, i tried to declare objFSO like : Dim objFSO AS FileSystemObject but getting error. Could you please help me.

Comment: Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") would work just fine... Why would you want to declare it like anything else.

Comment: Let me try again.

Comment: It's Not Working. I am not getting any Error, but file name is still same

Comment: @RajeshGurbani no it cannot happen. both methods should work fine. see my updated answer.